# User account registration at own site based on Google or other accounts

Tags: android, mysql, facebook, google-api, authorization

I'm setting up a new REST web service with accompanying Android app for existing entertainment portal. I stopped where unlike that portal I would like let Android users sign in using their Google or Facebook accounts.
Singing in would let people leave comments on the portal, but the database constrains require the presence of the user account in the same database (for example, every Comment record references user_id record in Users table).

So I need creating my own user accounts based on Google/Facebook profiles, right ? How would you recommend to approach this ?

I'm concerned about what should be the unique identifier of account in my own database ? Currently in this **legacy** database it is just a 'login'. I can compose login from people's Given and Last names, but this may clash of course.
Should this be a composite key like 'login' + 'account_origin' where account_origin is 'legacy / google / facebook / others...' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally record IDs should be controlled solely by your service. I personally like to always use [UUID4s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_4_.28random.29) ([pros/cons](http://blog.codinghorror.com/primary-keys-ids-versus-guids/)), some like to use sequential IDs that are common as SQL primary keys.

An extensible identity resource could look like this:

```
{
    "id": "2d19b086-d8eb-11e4-b9d6-1681e6b88ec1",
    "name": "Kitten Smith",
    "emails": ["kitten@example.com", "kittensmith@example.org"],
    "profiles": [{
        "id": "1234",
        "service": "facebook"
    }, {
        "id": "5678",
        "service": "google"
    }]
}
```

Now that is obviously somewhat complex and depending on your database you might want to split `emails` and `profiles` into their own tables. The nice aspect of this though is a single user can add as many emails and third-party profiles they want to thier single identity.

If you wanted a more limited version where users can only have a single email and one profile from each network you could do something like this:

```
{
    "id": "2d19b086-d8eb-11e4-b9d6-1681e6b88ec1",
    "name": "Kitten Smith",
    "email": "kitten@example.com",
    "facebook_id": "1234",
    "google_id": "5678"
}
```

Comment: Useful examples, thank you. Many sites provide sign in function using external credentials I was wondering what they do with it, they were supposed to transform external profile into internal one. Despite of this widely used approach I was unable to find any information related to this